# Datapager url rewriting with querystring

Tags: asp.net, listview, url-rewriting, datapager

I have a ListView with DataPager.Firstly my url is:
http://www.etkinpatent.com/marka-tescil.html 
If I click page 2 from DataPager my url looks like this: http://www.etkinpatent.com/icerikler.aspx?ID=41&sayfa=2
I want url sholud be like this: http://www.etkinpatent.com/marka-tescil.html/2 or
http://www.etkinpatent.com/2/marka-tescil.html
or it shouldnt change like this again:http://www.etkinpatent.com/marka-tescil.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out URLMapping or URLRewrite for this. You can google for these words and am sure you will get a fix.

Cheers

Vasan